# I want to walk up the visual tree of an Angular 4x application

Tags: angular

I'm in an Angular4x component. I want to find a parent component, maybe one to two levels above. I'm using ng-content in the parent so normal input bindings aren't working for me.  I'm good with walking up the tree in code, to grab parent. But how would I do that.  In WPF I'd use the VisualTreeHelper which uses the .parent property of every component.

What I'm looking for here is to the get the objectId of app-report-container (a numeric property) to the app-two-dates (see reportContainerId) (any way possible)

```js
  <app-report-container
    container-title="Sales Dashboard"
    report-template="SalesDashboard"
    get-data="getSalesDashboardData"
    minimum-rptsection-height="107px"
    style="width: 1000px"
  >

    <app-two-dates date1text="Period1:" date2text="Period2:" reportContainerId="{{objectIdOfAppReportContainer}}"></app-two-dates>

  </app-report-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up providing a service at the parent level, then consuming that service in the child level (app-two-dates). Works great.